# Telerik control issue while convert asp.net website to web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I was trying to convert Asp.net website to web application. In that I'm facing telerik control issue - Asp.net controls were converted in designer page but Telerik control is not converting. 
The name 'RadScriptManager1' does not exist in the current context.

I have chosen asp.net empty website and referenced telerik dll. Added one aspx page- It has telerik controls.

Could you please suggest some solution to resolve this.

Comment: is 4 part name assembly property of telerik registration tag?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing **telerik tagPrefix**. If so, you can either add tagPrefix in web.config

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>
      ...
    </controls>
  </pages>
  ...
</system.web>
```

Or you can add the top of every .aspx and .ascx page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
```

I personally prefer the first approach.